Swift 6: Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type in a @Sendable closure
Context
Consider this simple example, where we have an Actor and a Class which holds a reference to that Actor:
actor MyActor
{
    func doWork() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}



class MyClass
{
    let worker: MyActor = MyActor()
    
    func swift6IsJustGreat()
    {
        Task {
            let number: Int = await worker.doWork()   // ERROR: Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'MyClass' in a `@Sendable` closure
            print(number)
        }
    }
}

Question
Xcode 16 Beta 1, when using Swift 6 Language Mode, shows this error on the line where we attempt to use the actor:
Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'MyClass' in a `@Sendable` closure

I understand the error. worker is a property of MyClass and the Task closure is capturing the instance of MyClass, which is not Sendable. Got it. But then...how the hell do I use anything in concurrency unless it's a global?
If my actor is an iVar on a non-Sendable class, how can I ever call anything on the actor?

Capture worker into the Task rather than self:
Task { [worker] in  // This makes a local copy of `self.worker`
    let number: Int = await worker.doWork()   // No problem
    print(number)
}

The Task does not actually need self. It doesn't do anything with it, and since worker is a let property, it is impossible for it to change between the time Task begins and when worker is used. (If it were var, then it would be even more important that it be captured rather than self, since it could change in a thread-unsafe way.)
An Actor is always Sendable, so can always be captured by a Task.

Floating Task are the source of many concurrency issues. The idea that an operation should be "let lose" is an old way of thinking you should just add the word async to the method.
import Foundation

actor MyActor
{
    func doWork() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}



class MyClass
{
    let worker: MyActor = MyActor()
    
    func swift6IsJustGreat() async
    {
        let number: Int = await worker.doWork() 
        print(number)
    }
}


This just kicks the Task{} closure up a level, to whatever calls the function, though. At some point I need Task{} to bridge into concurrency—this is an AppKit-based app.

@Bryan UI is tied to the MainActor it becomes a non-issue then. But you should also hang on to the task for many reasons, don’t leave it floating.

I have no idea if it's the best solution, but assigning MyClass to a specific actor removed the error:
@MainActor
class MyClass
{ 
   ... 
}

This is not an intuitive solution, given the error message, but it’s one of the presented options in Apple’s “common concurrency errors” document:
https://www.swift.org/migration/documentation/swift-6-concurrency-migration-guide/commonproblems/
